# PowerEdge T100 fails to boot without display+keyboard

Tags: boot, dell-poweredge, headless

Our office has an old Dell PowerEdge T100 , which I'm recently setting up with Ubuntu 18.04. For space efficiency and we leave no mouse/keyboard+display connected.

Thing is, once we power up our server without keyboard+mouse+monitor it is simply blinking its power button/switch and not starting.  With mouse/keyboard+display, however, it is starting alright.

Any work arround to start it actually without monitor+mouse+keyboard?

Comment: Maybe something useful is displayed when you plug in the display after booting without. Check the BIOS for settings that may effect headless mode or for settings that will wait and prompt for user input on warnings (such as the warning that no display is attached) because server models should be able to boot and operate in headless mode

Comment: One thing I had done is that, I had installed Ubuntu desktop,setup ssh, and then I removed xorg.